# Nokogiri, how to elegantly grab the value of child elements and attributes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using nokogiri and my object graph when looping looks like:

```
  #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe7b34a49c8 name="dt" children=[#
<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe7b34a4720 name="a" attributes=[#
<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe7b34a46bc name="href" value="http://www.example.com">, #
<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe7b34a4694 name="add_date" value="1246334352997870">] children=[#
<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe7b34a39c4 "Example.com Website ">]>, #
<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe7b34a35f0 "\n">,
```

I want to load this information into this class:

```
class LinkInfo
  attr_accessor :href, :add_date, :text
end

href = http://www.example.com
add_date = 1246334352997870
text = "example.com website"
```

Is there an elegant way to do this, I'm currently looping through the children, and doing things with if statements to see if I am at the right tag name etc.

I know in ruby you can see if a value is in a collection using contains?, but I also want to then get the value of that.

Comment: Please state your question. Also, provide a snippet of the HTML and tell us what output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML is identical to your last question:

```
<dl><p>
  <dt><h3 ADD_DATE="120ssssss">label 1</H#>
</dl>
<dl><p>
  <dt><a href="http://www.example.com" ADD_DATE="12312323">Text 1</A>
  <dt><a href="http://www.example.com" ADD_DATE="12312323">Text 2</A>
  <dt><a href="http://www.example.com" ADD_DATE="12312323">Text 3</A>
</dl>

<dl><p>
  <dt><h3 ADD_DATE="120ssssss">label 2</H#>
</dl>
<dl><p>
  <dt><a href="http://www.example.com" ADD_DATE="12312323">Text 1</A>
  <dt><a href="http://www.example.com" ADD_DATE="12312323">Text 2</A>
  <dt><a href="http://www.example.com" ADD_DATE="12312323">Text 3</A>
</dl>
```

Then you can do this:

```
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)

links = doc.css('dl dt a').map do |link|
  li = LinkInfo.new
  li.href = link['href']
  li.add_date = link['ADD_DATE']
  li.text = link.text
  li
end
```

Comment: doe smap flatten all the child objects?

Comment: No, map returns an element in the return array for each element in the input. In this case it means that for each matching `a` element, it returns a LinkInfo object. So `links` is an array of LinkInfo objects.

Comment: is it possible to test if link has the key?  I tried link.contains? "href" but got an error saying contains isn't a method.

Comment: oh I actually did: doc.xpath("//dl/dt") because I need both the label, and then the links under the label.

Comment: `link` isn't a `Hash`. It's a Nokogiri `Node` object. Also, you didn't say anything about the label.